# Why some reference assemblies is locked and how to remove them, in Multitarget project?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, projects-and-solutions, multitargeting

This is a multitarget project, contains .net 2.0 and 4.0 two target frameworks, here have some reference items is locked, but I'm not ref them at all in .csproj, please tell me why these dlls at here and locked, how to let them get out of here?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I know the answer, from https://github.com/microsoft/msbuild/issues/4530

In .csproj>Project>PropertyGroup, add `DisableImplicitFrameworkReferences`, like this:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <DisableImplicitFrameworkReferences>true</DisableImplicitFrameworkReferences>
</PropertyGroup>
```